# CORS errors but only with special characters in URL

Tags: angular, aws-api-gateway

My client side web app is written using Angular, and server side is AWS API gateway.

I'm getting the error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at <my destiniation> from origin <my origin> has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Where `<my destination>` and `<my origin>` are not the same domain.

The problem is that I do have CORS setup to support this. My setup uses a preflight OPTIONS request, followed by a PUT request (the PUT is what is failing with a 403, and console shows the CORS error). The response from the OPTIONS request does in fact include `access-control-allow-origin: *` and the strangest thing is that my PUT request will only fail if one (or more) of my URL parameter arguments contains a %23 in it (for example, as the result of URL encoding a # symbol).

Does anyone know why special characters in URL parameters would trigger a CORS error while the exact same request without the special characters passes CORS without any issue? What could I be missing?

Comment: When a request fails due to a %23 in the request URL, what is the HTTP status code of the response? If the status code of the response isn’t a 200 OK, but instead a 4xx or 5xx error response, then you don’t actually have a CORS problem to solve. Instead you have a 4xx or 5xx error problem to solve.

Comment: The preflight OPTIONS succeeds with a 200, but the following PUT fails with a 403. You think that means the CORS is a red herring?

Comment: Yeah, if you’re getting a 403, then the CORS relationship to the cause is red herring. So whatever’s causing you to hit that 403, it’s not your CORS config. The only reason the browser is mentioning CORS in the error message you cited is because the server didn’t add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to that 403 response. CORS config on a server is never going to cause a server to reject a request — all the actual CORS blocking is done by the browser on the client side. The only thing CORS config is going to cause to happen is to make the server send Access-Control-Allow-\* headers.

Comment: Thanks! This helped a ton.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the help from [sideshowbarker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/441757/sideshowbarker) I was able to solve this. It turns out that the CORS error was in fact a red herring.

After digging a bit deeper, I learned that the AWS signature wasn't matching (but only when including special characters), and I found out that I needed to double encode my parameters in order for the signature to be calculated properly. I did this with `decodeURIComponent()` on each parameter that might contain special characters, and then I used `decodeURI()` on the resulting entire URL (effectively double encoding the problematic parameters). The signature now passes and the requests succeeds.

This problem/solution is probably unique to how my client side app (in Angular) is working with AWS signatures, but it may come in handy for someone else who is getting similar errors.

Comment: Man, you saved me half a day of going bald. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of inspecting the same problem it turned out to be a red herring as jrel commented.
In my particular case the problem was in our nginx server and the modsecurity + Owasp CRS rules installed on the machine. Every time it was detecting a query string in the URL the request was blocked due to possible XSS attack.

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem arose here as well.
The cause, however, was somewhat different. Whenever a preflight request preceded a request, a CORS error with 403 status occurred.
The reason for this was that the POST requests in this particular case worked exclusively with url parameters. The used Tomcat server, however, seems to expect a filled Content-Type header for POST requests, which was removed by the client-side library, because there was no data attribute.
Since we can ensure that such requests always contain a Content-Type and at least an empty "data":{}, neither the 403 nor the CORS error occurs.
But as said this effect only occurred when the browser issued a preflight request.
Maybe it helps someone ;)